# Как создать службу windows на Golang?

Tags: golang, service, служба, веб-служба

Нужно создать службу,поставить ее в автозагрузку и общаться с ней. Как обычные приложения делать-понятно,а вот как то же приложение сделать службой?
Спасибо

Comment: Живой пример: [руководство по GoGS](https://gogs.io/docs/installation/run_as_windows_service).

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc

Answer (score 6):

предлагаю 2 варианта:

1. Пишешь обычную go программу, которая крутится в бесконечном цикле и делает что надо (слушает порты/сигналы/файлы и так ты с ней общаешься). Потом с помощью программы [nssm](http://nssm.cc/) инсталируешь ее как сервис MyService: `nssm install MyService d:\MyService.exe` и управляешь из службы сервисов или тем же nssm.
2. Без сторонних программ. Есть пакет [svc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc) из дополнений. С помощью него можно создать программу которая интегрируется в службу сервисов и понимает все комманды от этой службы, причем ты сам определяешь поведение на переданные комманды (пауза, продолжение), чего в случае 1 ты сделать не можешь. Там даже есть пример такого простенького сервиса [example](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc/example). Можешь взять за основу его и изменить метод main под свои нужды.